# Adding shapefile layer in PostGis creates two tables

Tags: postgis, shapefile, qgis-3

When I try to upload a shapefile to my PostGIS database, it creates two tables (I can see them in QGIS). I import them by drag and dropping them on the PostGIS connection.

If I delete one of them, both disappear. While it doesn't hurt, it seems worrying.

For a reason I don't understand, it happens especially with Lambert-93 tables.

If I am doing it wrong, how can I fix that?

[image]

Comment: how are you importing it into postgres?

Comment: I drag and drop them from the layer pane to the PostGIS section in the explorer pane.

Comment: could u add a screenshot of what you see ? your two tables are probably for some reason one unique table ...

Comment: if you go into postgres are there two tables there?

Comment: maybe in postgres run `select distinct st_srid(geom) from yourtable` see what you get

Comment: Look at both layer properties. It will tell you the source, projection etc. Look for difference between the two.